# How to change snap UV grid

Tags: uv, snapping

I'm trying to snap UV into little units.
Even if I did mange to change the grid size and snap correctfully in Modeling window,

I cannot find a way to do the same in the UV Edit window (even by pressing Shift, the snap is too wide)

Comment: It's possible to Snap to Pixels. In the UV editor, UV menu,  open the Snap to Pixel option and choose either to snap to the Corner or the Center of a pixel.

Comment: it still doesn't match. My texture is a 64x64 pixel wide. The snap pass by 4 pixels by 4 pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops no, @3fingeredfrog was right :
In order to snap correctly to pixels you have to choose the Snap to Pixel option but ALSO have to UNCHECK the snap magnet tool into the main toolbar, or else this will be the main snap overriding the snap pixel option.

Thanks again